# Auto upload files to Google Drive using python script

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-oauth, pydrive

I have the following code that auto authenticates/authorizes my google drive access. I have copied the client_secrets.json file in my script's parent directory. The code opens a browser tab and waits for me to click "Accept". After I accept, the code continues to run, creates a folder (if not existing) and stores my file to it.

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

# Find the folder id 
id = 0;
file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': "'root' in parents and trashed=false"}).GetList()
for file1 in file_list:
    if file1['title'] == gpath:
        id = file1['id']

# Make folder if it does not exist
if id == 0:
    file1 = drive.CreateFile({'title': gpath, 'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'})
    file1.Upload()

# Fetch the folder id
file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': "'root' in parents and trashed=false"}).GetList()
for file1 in file_list:
    if file1['title'] == gpath:
        id = file1['id']

# Upload file to folder
file1 = drive.CreateFile({'title': fname, "parents":  [{"kind": "drive#fileLink","id": id}]})
file1.SetContentFile(fname)
file1.Upload()
```

I want to run this script on a remote server and don't know if the server has a browser and/or if the script will run successfully on it. I would like to fully automate the process and not have the user click "Accept" on a browser and instead let the script handle everything without user intervention.

Also this is part of a very large script that runs for hours and will probably be programmed to run automatically every week or so. Hence any user dependence is highly undesirable.

---

I have tried [Gerardo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4044241/gerardo)'s method (from 2nd comment). I think I may have succeeded in auto authenticating my application. I created a service account and used SignedJwtAssertionCredentials to generate an authorized http object as follows:

```
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
from httplib2 import Http

client_email = 'xyz@developer.gserviceaccount.com'
with open("MyProject.p12") as f:
    private_key = f.read()

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(client_email, private_key, 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin', sub='abc@example.com')
gauth = credentials.authorize(Http())
```

Not sure if my app is getting authorized. It does not throw any errors, so I think it should work. I still need to upload my files to a folder. How do I proceed?

Comment: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zJVCKvXtHtE) this video describes how to generate a client ID for your program, so that you don't need to click Accept

Comment: I already have a client ID, client secret, token uri, etc. Its all in the client_secrets.json file. My command line python application auto authenticates itself but it still requires me to click Accept in my browser. This is the part that I need help with.

Comment: according to the documentation, all the different kind of interactions with OAuth require user actions, except Service Account. Here is the documentation check if that would be suitable for your application https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount